# Stability of dynamical system described in polar coordinates

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates

Near a fixed point, a dynamical system $\dot{\bf{x}}=\bf{F}(\bf{x})$ can be approximated by $\dot{\bf{x}}=A\bf{x}$, where $A$ is the Jacobian matrix. From the trace and determinant of the Jacobian $A$, we can determine the property of the fixed point, i.e., stable/unstable node/spiral, etc. However, usually this is shown in Cartesian coordinates. If I write the dynamical system in

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{r}\\
\dot{\theta}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=A\begin{pmatrix}
r\\
\theta\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
near a fixed point. 
**My question** is, what does $A$ tell us about the property of the fixed point? 
Do the things that hold for Cartesian coordinates also hold for polar coordinate (e.g. trace and determinant of the Jacobian $A$ determines the property of the fixed point)? Why?

Comment: If the system of polar coordinates is centered at the fixed point, stability should probably be equivalent to $A_{11}\leqslant0$ and $A_{12}=0$.

Comment: @Did, Could you show (or prove) this in an answer?

Comment: That $A_{11}\lt0$ and $A_{12}=0$ imply stability should be within your reach. The stronger statement in my first comment is probably slightly too strong to be true.